# XML indentation using plugin for VS code - Wrap Attributes

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins, formatter

I am looking for a way to use the plugin [VS Code Pretty Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mblode.pretty-formatter) or some else plugin for ident XML files and its classes in two ways: Block and Inline.
Is there some way I can get a result similar to it and is it possible to create a keyboard shortcut?

For example:
[image: block and inline indentation]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [XML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-xml) extension can format XML files, and the default shortcut key is `Shift+Alt+F` (or select `Format Document` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)). You can change the formatting style with `xml.format.splitAttributes` in the [settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).